# Right design pattern to implement Oops in the right manner for my use case

Tags: java, object, design-patterns, singleton, instantiation

I came across a problem where I'm supposed to build a report for a company. The user first creates the company, then adds the employees and then generates reports based on employee data.

To solve this problem, I've created a singleton class for the company and all modifications (addition, removal and report generation for employs) is done using the single object created.

Now, suppose I've to extend this problem and create multiples companies and maintain multiple reports for all companies individually (no persistance, its a practice code to use OOPs efficiently).

The best solution I can come up with is, to create a hashmap of `<name of company, object for that company>` in the calling layer of the code.

For that I have to make necessary changes in the "Company" class of my code. (Constructor will accept name of company)

Everything else will be handled in the calling layer.

Is there any other efficient way to do this? Any OOPs principles that can be used efficiently or any design pattern that should be followed in such scenarios?

I'm relatively new to Object oriented programming and hence, I dont know the best way to go ahead

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a new Reporter class which accepts a company in the constructor and has one method: `generateReports()`.

This method will spin up a thread which will generate the reports for all the employees of that company.

Now you can created multiple reporter instances (one per company) and when you'll call them to generate the reports - they'll work in parallel so that IO calls won't block the execution as it would be in case you'd run serially on all the companies.

Answer (score 0):

> I've created a singleton class for the company

Conceptually it is wrong because you have several companies.
Here you should have a  class `Company` and instantiate it with distinct parameters that defines a company. Then just use the instances of that to populate data.
OOP features such as subclassing `Company` could make sense  if some behaviors are common between them but that some companies may make them differ (overriding or new functions).   But as you don't precise this point, I let you judge.

Comment: Thank you, I created a singleton class only when my use case involved a single company. 

Now when Im extending the problem to cater multiple use cases, I'm creating objects based on how many companies the user wants to create and then storing the company name and its object in a hashmap. 
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should edit your code and provide a concrete code that represents your question.